# Unknown class file creation by Eclipse java

Tags: java, eclipse, .class-file

Hi I am working on a java project. I am using eclipse as an IDE. I have a file FileProvider.java in the package com.ibm.wala.util.io. For this file Eclipse is making two class files FileProvider.class and FileProvider$EclipseUtil.class. Can someone tell me why Eclipse is creating second class file.

Comment: Read about the inner/nested classes http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you defined an inner class called `EclipseUtil` in `FileProvider`.

Answer (score 4):

You have an inner class called EclipseUtil in your FileProvider class.

Answer (score 2):

As your FileProvider.java has declared EclipseUtil as inner class.